# Filter part of image using PIL

Tags: python, filtering, python-imaging-library

How to apply blur filter to part of an image using PIL?

Comment: I tried to crop image and apply filter to its part.
But I believe there is more simple and correct way.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you cropped the image and tried to apply the filter. It is hard for us to suggest a more simple and correct way if we don't know what your current way of doing things is.

Answer (score 20):

You can crop out a section of the image, blur it, and stick it back in.  Like this:

```
box = (30, 30, 110, 110)
ic = image.crop(box)
for i in range(10):  # with the BLUR filter, you can blur a few times to get the effect you're seeking
    ic = ic.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
image.paste(ic, box)
```

[image]

Below is the full code I used to generate the chess board, save the image, etc.  (This isn't the most efficient way to generate a chessboard, etc, it's just for the demo.)

```
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
from itertools import cycle

def draw_chessboard(n=8, pixel_width=200):
    "Draw an n x n chessboard using PIL."
    def sq_start(i):
        "Return the x/y start coord of the square at column/row i."
        return i * pixel_width / n

    def square(i, j):
        "Return the square corners, suitable for use in PIL drawings" 
        return map(sq_start, [i, j, i + 1, j + 1])

    image = Image.new("L", (pixel_width, pixel_width))
    draw_square = ImageDraw.Draw(image).rectangle
    squares = (square(i, j)
               for i_start, j in zip(cycle((0, 1)), range(n))
               for i in range(i_start, n, 2))
    for sq in squares:
        draw_square(sq, fill='white')
    image.save("chessboard-pil.png")
    return image

image = draw_chessboard()

box = (30, 30, 110, 110)

ic = image.crop(box)

for i in range(10):
    ic = ic.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)

image.paste(ic, box)

image.save("blurred.png")
image.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    draw_chessboard()
```

Comment: How do you save the blurred image? The code seems to run when I try this solution but no part of the original image gets blurred? Should I be adding any lines to save the image as another file ? If so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Veejay: you should be able to use `image.save("blurred.png")` to save the image, and `image.show()` to show the image in your default viewer (if you have one).  I'll also edit my answer to post the code I used to generate the chessboard image as well (which I still happen to have).

Answer (score 7):

I am just adding to the above answer posted by @tom10.

```
# importing PILLOW library.
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

image = Image.open('path/to/image_file')
box = (30, 30, 110, 110)
crop_img = image.crop(box)
# Use GaussianBlur directly to blur the image 10 times. 
blur_image = crop_img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=10))
image.paste(blur_image, box)
image.save('path/to/save_image_file')
```

I have just replaced the ***ImageFilter.Blur*** with ***ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=10)***. You can change the amount of blur by changing the radius value.