# Python - Image Filter BLUR selected Region

Tags: python, image-processing, render, python-imaging-library, blur

How to create a strong blur (I can try looping) a certain part of image as defined by cooridnates as such. I have scanned TIF images with some ADDRESS field in the right top side. I need to automate a script to BLUR it, OVERLAP it, HIDE it or whatever and rest keep the scan copy as it is.

Code Example - I have an image 300 x 300 and I want to blur only the down right 50 x 50 pixel square. How to be selective with it. Read about the PIL and ImageFilter.BLUR but couldn't find a way out. Also tried to overlap the part with another image but PASTE function takes the same size.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701515/filter-part-of-image-using-pil-python