# blurring an image with image.crop() - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I've got an image and I want to blur a section of it.

The output I'm looking for is like the partially blurred chessboard seen in this [Filter part of image using PIL, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701515/filter-part-of-image-using-pil-python) answer.

I've tried using the code from the above answer, but I get an error message saying:

`----> 2 ic = image.crop(box)`

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'`

How do I move forward? Should I be trying to convert the np.ndarry to an image??

Thanks!

```
# libraries 
import cv2
from PIL import Image

# read in  
path = 'C://Users/my_account//Desktop//robert_downey_jr_image.png'
image = cv2.imread(path)

# blurring 
box = (30, 30, 110, 110)  
ic = image.crop(box)
for i in range(10):  
    ic = ic.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
image.paste(ic, box)

image.show()

# ERROR MESSAGE 
----> 2 ic = image.crop(box)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'crop'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is just a NumPy array, which does not have the attribute crop as you say.

You need to open it with the PIL Image library with:

```
image = Image.open(path)
```

Then you can call crop. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html